# Where dagger2 stores scoped instances?

Tags: dagger-2

I have scoped component with annotation @Singleton. It requires DbModule. I peeked into generated class, and I found that there are Factories for DbModule functions (annotated @Singleton as well). Factory uses DbModule function directrly so it provides new instance every time get() factory's method called, and this instance never stored. Factory then saved in component as provider. So the question is how dagger provides same instance for same scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Factory then saved in component as provider.

This is almost true, but not quite.  The generated component code looks something like this:

```
this.provideDatabaseProvider = DoubleCheck.provider(DbModule_ProvideDatabaseFactory.create());
```

The `DoubleCheck.provider` method returns an instance of `DoubleCheck` that delegates to the original provider.  This, and not the original factory, is saved in the component.

The `get` implementation in `DoubleCheck` then calls the delegate `Provider` exactly once and stores the result.  Each subsequent call to `get` returns the instance stored earlier.